# Converting all .pdf files in folder tree to .png

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm on Ubuntu, and I have a tree of folders containing .pdf files.  I need to convert each one to a .png format.  The bash script I am currently using is:

```
for f in $(find ./polkadots -name 'image.pdf'); do
convert -transparent white -fuzz 10% $f image.png;
done
```

I have tested the for loop by itself, and it works (it produces a list of all the .pdf files under the ./polkadots folder that I need to convert):

```
for f in $(find ./polkadots -name 'image.pdf'); do
echo "$f";
done
```

I have tested the imagemagic convert command by itself, and it works (it converts a single file in my current directory from .pdf to .png):

```
convert -transparent white -fuzz 10% image.pdf image.png
```

However, when I combine them... the console sits and thinks for a while, and then concludes.. but no files have been created or changed, and no error messages are produced.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The new .png files are being created, but they are being created in my current directory, instead of in the sub-directory where the .pdf was found.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `find` alone. No need to use a loop.

I haven't tested this command but it *should* work.

`find ./polkadots -name 'image.pdf' -exec convert -transparent white -fuzz 10% {} image.png \; -print`

The `-print` at the end is optional. I prefer to see which files have been modified.

Comment: I tried your command, but as soon as I hit enter, it just pops up a new command line.  Doesn't take the time I'd expect to process, and no new files appear to have been created anywhere.

Comment: In which dir are you executing the search? Try `find full_path_to_the_dir ...`

Comment: Hm... with your edit (adding the extra quotation), it now prints out "find: missing argument to '-exec'".  The path is accurate - I have tested that several times.  Like I said above, if I just do a "find" to locate all the .pdfs, it prints out the accurate list

Comment: I also edited my problem - my original script was converting the files, but it was converting them to a .png in the directory I started in (./), not in the directory where it found the .pdf to convert (./polkadots/*/* etc)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find output option in convert command directly, which can export the png file to your expect folder. Anyway follow your idea, here is the updated code:

```
find ./polkadots -type f -name "image.pdf" |while read line
do  
   dir=${line%/*}
   convert -transparent white -fuzz 10% $line image.png
   mv image.png ${dir}/image.png
done
```

If you need convert all pdf files under polkadots folder, try this:

```
find ./polkadots -type f -name "*.pdf" |while read line
do  
   dir=${line%/*}
   file=${line##*/}
   file=${file%.*}
   convert -transparent white -fuzz 10% $line ${file}.png
   echo mv ${file}.png ${dir}/${file}.png
done
```

Comment: Yes, I need to convert all .pdf files in the tree (they are all named "image.pdf").

Comment: sure, then how about the first one, it should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash 4+, you should use globstar instead of find

```
#!/bin/bash 
shopt -s globstar
for f in ./polkadots/**/image.pdf; do
  convert -transparent white -fuzz 10% "$f" "${f%/*}/image.png"
done
```

If you're using an older bash, your original answer is close to fine, but has a few bugs/potential bugs,

- If you directories have spaces in them, your original script will case errors, so use the `| while read -r -d '' f` syntax.
- Don't put a `;` at the end of command lines
- Quote all variables to prevent expansion problems
- As you pointed out, main issue in your case was not specifying destination dir, so you can use `${f%/*}` parameter expansion to get the dir (this will delete everything including and after the last `/` in $f, then put the `/` back and append the filename like below.

Edited

```
#!/bin/bash
find ./polkadots -name "image.pdf" -print0 | while read -r -d '' f; do
  convert -transparent white -fuzz 10% "$f" "${f%/*}/image.png"
done
```